# How to add a href to a binded list using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have binded a list to an object in the controller and then use a th:each construct to loop through it. My objective is to allow the user to view the content of the object but update only one field of the object (the weight field) as well as allow a detele functionality. My code below works with the exception of the th:href to delete a particular asset. It seems that he correct id is not passed back to the controller. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<tr th:each="asset, itemStat : *{assets}">
                            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{assets[__${itemStat.index}__].id}">
                            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{assets[__${itemStat.index}__].symbol}">
                            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{assets[__${itemStat.index}__].name}">
                            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${asset.symbol}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${asset.name}"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input size="4" style="text-align: center" th:field="*{assets[__${itemStat.index}__].weight}"/></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><a th:href="${'/asset/delete/' + asset.id}"></a></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What you have looks correct, what's the actual error? When you view the source does the id show up in the hidden field as well as the href?

Comment: The same id shows up in the hidden field and the href. However, the delete link does not appear in the html page. It does and deletes the asset as required if I convert the loop to a simple table to display the list of assets without the input field.

Comment: The delete link doesn't appear because there is no text in it.  if you want text, you need to add it.  For example: `<a th:href="${'/asset/delete/' + asset.id}">Delete</a>`

Comment: Also, I recommend creating links using [Thymeleaf standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).  Like this: `<a th:href="@{/asset/delete/{id}(id=${asset.id})}">Delete</a>`

Comment: Silly me. I have spent hours on this problem. Many thanks for your help and for saving me who knows how much more time. I will use the recommended syntax from now on. All the best.